# Clean install of Mavericks via Snow Leopard using Time machine dat recovery

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, time-machine, backup, garageband

When purchased, my iMac came with Snow Leopard, plus installation disks, but I recently upgraded the OS to Mavericks, in order to use the latest iteration of Garageband, i.e. Garageband 10.1.

Garageband 10.1 does not run at all well, but I don't know whether it is a glitchy, buggy program, or a system wide issue on my machine causing the problem. It occurred to me I might back up the system I currently run using Time Machine to preserve data, perform a clean install, using my Snow Leopard disks, then upgrade via the App store back to Mavericks, (because Garageband 10.1 cannot run on Snow Leopard), which would effectively give me clean Mavericks installation. I would then reinstall my data from my Time Machine Back up.

Is this a sensible approach which might work? I'd appreciate any advice. Many thanks, George Bolam.

Comment: What type of computer and how much RAM does it have?

Comment: If you are thinking about reinstalling mavericks why not use the recovery partition to do it? this way you don't have to install snow leopard first.

Comment: Dwight asks a relevant question. Why? Because Garageband uses a lot of resources, both disk, Processor and RAM and your issue could simply be running out of resources and a Mac that came with Snow Leopard, depending on the configuration, could need more RAM (at the least).

Comment: Thanks for asking dwightk: late 2009 iMac 16GB Ram Intel duo core

Comment: @dennismuys: I wanted to completely rebuild the computer HD as if the machine was just coming out of the box, in order to ensure a clean, incorrupt system. I would then upgrade to Mavericks, then reinstall Garageband 10.1.  The only 'data' I would need to recover are existing personal files, (photo's, documents etc. and a few Apps I've added that do not impact on the Garageband issue) plus of course some garageband files. :-)

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to backup your system but you don't need to reinstall your computer via DVD. Instead there is a terminal script which will take the version of the Mavericks installer you got from the Mac App Store and install it on a USB stick. Pretty sweet stuff: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5856

You need a USB stick roughly 8 GB or larger and it should be erase before hand. There is another version of the command line that is as follows

> sudo "/Applications/Install OS X Mavericks.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia" --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath "/Applications/Install OS X Mavericks.app"

With this the USB drive needs to be called Untitled and this will do all the necessary steps in the background. Be aware it will take 30-40 minutes for this to copy over but when it is done you'll see a $ sign.

Now with that created please restart your mac, hold down alt and choose your USB device. Once you have the install option erase your hard drive through Disk Utility and then you can proceed with a fresh install of Mavericks.

I would recommend re-downloading Garageband from the Mac App Store fresh instead of transferring it from TimeMachine... hope this helps you out and if you have further questions just comment.

Comment: @ Andrew U Thank you! I'll look into this, but please see my comments above. :-)

Comment: what am i suppose to look at?

Comment: My comments to 0ther people, above, that may give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do. :-)

Comment: Most of my info stands still so I'm good. Let me know if you have any troubles or exact questions.

Comment: Where's my brownie point i.e. up vote? ;)